# How to build graph paths from list of nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, tuples, networkx

What I am trying to do is build a graph in NetworkX, in which every node is a train station. To build the nodes I did:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(trains['Stopping place'].unique())
```

which (at least as it looks like) it's working.
Now, since for each line I have the stops in sequence, I built my paths like so:

```
stops_by_line = ((belgium_trains.sort_values(['Train number','Actual arrival datetime']).groupby('Train number'))['Stopping place'].apply(list).to_dict())
paths = ([tuple(val) for val in stops_by_line.values()])
```

and the variable looks like this:

```
[('HERGENRATH',
'CHENEE',
'ANGLEUR',
'LIEGE-GUILLEMINS',
'ANS',
'LEUVEN',
'HERENT',
'VELTEM',
'ERPS-KWERPS',
'KORTENBERG',
'NOSSEGEM',
'ZAVENTEM',
'DIEGEM',
'HAREN-ZUID',
'SCHAARBEEK',
'BRUSSEL-NOORD',
'BRUSSEL-CONGRES',
'BRUSSEL-CENTRAAL',
'BRUSSEL-KAPELLEKERK',
'BRUSSEL-ZUID'),
(...other ordered tuples of stops),...)]
```

Now my question is, since all of these elements are also node names, how can I build the edges using these tuples sequentially (for example add an edge between BRUSSEL-NOORD and BRUSSEL-CONGRES, then from BRUSSEL-CONGRES to BRUSSEL-CENTRAAL and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`add_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.add_path.html) method in a loop:

```
for path in paths:
    nx.add_path(G, path)
```

Sidemark, if you add an edge (like e.g. above), then `networkx` also directly adds the respective nodes to the graph. So probably (if all stops are covered by some train) you don't need to add the nodes manually before.